# Bookmarklet That Changes All Disabled Buttons To Enabled Buttons

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I was wondering if there was a way to make a bookmarklet that enabled all buttons on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

[David Grossberg’s “undisable” bookmarklet](https://squarefree.com/bookmarklets/forms.html#undisable) performs that task:

```
javascript:(function(){for(let k=0;k<document.forms.length;++k){const f=document.forms[k];for(let j=0;j<f.length;++j){f[j].disabled=false;f[j].readonly=false}}})()
```

Unwrapped, that is as follows. The script iterates through the document’s forms, removing `disabled` and `readonly` attributes:

```js
(function () {
  for (let k = 0; k < document.forms.length; ++k) {
    const f = document.forms[k]
    for (let j = 0; j < f.length; ++j) {
      f[j].disabled = false
      f[j].readonly = false
    }
  }
})()
```